# Record a GPS track in qfield?

Tags: qgis, gps, tracking, qfield

Okay I can't figure out for the life of me how to log a live GPS track in qfield. I can add points and draw polygons, both of which are useful, but how does one *track*? I am trying to use qfield to collect field data for natural resources inventories so I need to track stream courses, trails, stone walls, etc., while keeping property boundaries and other features (shapefiles) visible. Anyone know how to record a track?

Comment: see https://github.com/opengisch/QField/issues/111

Comment: I used sportstracker to record tracks https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.stt.android&hl=en